# input change event on enter key not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#inputBoxWidth").change(function() {
  var curValue = $("#inputBoxWidth").val();
  alert(curValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="inputBoxWidth">
</form>
```

When I press enter key in all browsers I get the alert function working except IE. In IE I have to click outside of the input element so the input looses focus and than it works. I need IE behave the same as other browser when pressing enter the alert popup shows up with the current value. How to do achieve that?

Comment: Why don;t you do it on `form-submit` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the `keyup` event.

Which gives you :

```
$("#inputBoxWidth").keyup(function() { // Your code });
```

Don't use the `keydown` event because if you want to get the value of the input it will give the value before the key was pressed.

:)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

> According to QuirksMode Chrome and Firefox have been compatible for some time, but IE9 and earlier versions of IE10 have incomplete support.

You're going to have to write some conditional code that explicitly checks if the browser is IE and write a work-around.